# How to get the scripttag url header values in javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have html page with script tag. In that script tag I am going to load external url, like..

```
<script src="http://www.test.com" />
```

Is it possible to read that url (http://www.test.com) header values by javascript.

Note: That script tag external url have iframe restriction.

Comment: somewhat unclear. please explain

Comment: @sagar: need to read the script tag url (http://www.test.com) header values

Comment: what do mean by header values? content-type, data-type, origin etc..?

Comment: for javascript file, there is no header values

Comment: @siam: yes need to take content-type, data-type, origin etc..

Comment: javascript doesn't have access to header values

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a .js file, then it can't have Header values.

Normally you can get the Header values via JavaScript by using Ajax Request.

for example:

```js
var url = "www.test.com";
var rh; // Response Headers
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",url,true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4){
    rh = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
  }
}

// now rh contain all headers

//or you can make a HEAD request which return all HEADER elements of the URL

xhr.open("HEAD", url,true);
 xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xhr.readyState==4) {
   rh = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
  }
 }
 xhr.send(null)
```

Comment: www.test.com/index is a page not a api service. If I load that page in ajax I have a timeout exception. So that reason I am asking to read header values from script tag.

Comment: what do you mean by HEADERS, meta values or Response Headers

Comment: You can't get it without Ajax Request because of security reasons.

Comment: Normally the `script` tag accept only javascript code.

Comment: If you have an entire page in a tag, then you can get the meta values. But not in case of script tag

Comment: consider marking it as answer. So that future visitors can refer it.